# gridview raise activity when scrolling until a specific item

Tags: android, gridview

So, I have a gridview and a lot of other widgets above it such as an imageview, recycleview (Horizontal), textview and more everything is fine,but I want my gridview to scroll the whole activity too when scrolling until it reaches the recycleview and then the recycleview goes above the gridview while scrolling till it reaches the top.
Then the gridview scrolls normally again.
Here is a more specific explanation:

This is what i have right now for example:

[image: What i have now]

I want this to happen when scrolling:

[image: what happens when scrolling]

And then the scrolling stops till here:

[image: after scrolling]

Then the gridview will begin to act normally again until i scroll back up!

Here is my code right now:

```
 <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/specialityicon"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/specialityicon"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/specialityicon"

        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/specialityicon"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/specialityicon"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.40"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.494"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="1" />



    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/reco"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="210dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/gridview2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.30"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.448"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.159"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.93" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="107dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/sadas"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/gridview2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recyclerView2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.45" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: First, let me know is there any specific reason for using GridView instead of RecyclerView (with GridLayoutManager)?

Comment: @SurajVaishnav I found it more suitable for me back then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `app:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` to your `GridView` and wrap your `ConstraintLayout` in `NestedScrollView`, like this:

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <ImageView.../>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.../>

    <GridView
        ...
    app:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
    ...
    />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Okay it works, but not like I wanted...
I can now scroll the whole activity but it doesn't show all my items any ideas?

Comment: Remove this app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.40", it is not needed